# How can I disable the page history of a Confluence wiki page

Tags: wiki, confluence

I have a page in my confluence wiki, that is generated automatically via a script and beeing pushed into confluence through its API. Therefore I don't need the history of this page, since  the number of page versions will add up very quickly.

Is there a way to turn off history keeping in Confluence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no way to turn it off. I don't know if you're appending to the page or completely recreating with each script run but if it's the later, you could delete the old page then create a new one each time instead.

Is there a specific problem having the page History causes for you?

Comment: the page is beeing automatically created every 5 Minutes, and it's a big list. So very quickly I would fill up the database with a lot of useless history.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Since this functionality is not available I'm using a workaround:

I remove all previous page versions but one with every API-call with https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CSOAP/Documentation#Documentation-removePageVersions

Comment: Try to just answer the question and put most of the logic in the answer rather than adding commentary about having the problem as well and mainly linking to an answer somewhere else (which may be moved / removed in future).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to disable backups for a single page, but you can at least choose whether to keep backups of an entire site or not.

To disable backup history for the whole site, go to site administration then click [Scheduled Jobs] underneath the Administration section.

From there you can disable the backup process.

Sorry I can't be of more help, that's the closest solution to your problem, that I know of.

Comment: turning the history off for the whole site is not an option in my case.